# Control not inheriting datacontext from parent?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there any reason for a control not to inherit the datacontext from its parent?

I've inherited a rather ugly piece of WPF code, which I've been tasked with updating. I want to change some text blocks from being hard coded strings to data bound values.

The basic layout I've got is

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="The Caption" />
</Grid>
```

which I've changed to

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BoundCaption}" />
</Grid>
```

However when I run the application, the textblock is blank.

Using WPF Snoop I can see that the grid has the expected datacontext (the view's viewmodel), but the datacontext of the textblock is null. If it makes any difference, the grid is actually used in a C1TabItem header (Component One library), so the visual tree is a mass of borders, content presenters, layout rounders etc. So far as I can tell there are no styles defined in the application for textblock.

I know I can get around this by directly setting the datacontext of the textblock explictly using

```
DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}"
```

but this ugly hack shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Write <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" /> so as to find out what is actual DataContext.

Comment: Hope you can show us more code for XAML you have.

Comment: It could be that the TextBox is not a logical child because of the use of the Component One library, so it would not inherit the DataContext

Comment: But the grid, which is the immediate parent, does have the correct datacontext.

Comment: Just a tip to get more debug info, try: <TextBlock Text="{Binding BoundCaption, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" /> and look in the debug output when launching the application. It might give you more information about the resolution of the binding

Comment: Adding PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High, just confirms that the  DataContext is null ...

Comment: The only thing I can think of is a style with a setter like: `<Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{x:Null}"/>`. Can there be a style for `TextBlock` in C# code, if not in xaml?

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, but can't find anything so far - this application is one big pile of spaghetti though, so who knows what is going on ...

Comment: This is strange that you `Binding` to `DataContext`. You should bind to _something_ inside (!) `DataContext`

Comment: _"this application is one big pile of spaghetti though"_ -- your first step, before even posting a question, should be to distill the "pile of spaghetti" to [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. There's far too little context here for anyone to answer the question.